# How do I toggle between UIWindows?

Tags: swift3, uiwindow

Scenario:

I've created an overlay window (with tag = 100) that I eventually want to dismiss.  But the following code doesn't work:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.becomeKey()
UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.resignKey()


(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.windows
▿ 2 elements
  - 0 : <UIWindow: 0x7fa698d0ad00; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000048550>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6000000278a0>>
  - 1 : <UIWindow: 0x7fa698d14bb0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; tag = 100; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000252a50>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x600000229660>>
```

Any ideas to either toggle or delete the overlay window?

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the window's `isHidden` property to true:

```
var overlayWindow: UIWindow?
...
overlayWindow?.isHidden = true
overlayWindow = nil  // optional
```

If you set any references to this window to nil, the window will be disposed.

Please also note that you are not supposed to call `resignKey()`. From [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow/1621618-resignkey) (emphasis mine):

> **Discussion**
>   *Never call this method directly.* The system calls this
>   method and posts UIWindowDidResignKey to let the window know when it
>   is no longer key. The default implementation of this method does
>   nothing, but subclasses can override it and use it to perform tasks
>   related to resigning the key window status.

The same is true for `becomeKey()`, by the way. You probably want to use [makeKey()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow/1621610-makekey) or [makeKeyAndVisible()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow/1621601-makekeyandvisible).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've also added a parallel question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220382/why-do-i-not-see-my-new-uiwindow

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a two-part question.

1. How do I display a created UIWindow and
2. How do I dismiss it?

I learned that I have to [keep a reference to the newly-created UIWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220382/why-do-i-not-see-my-new-uiwindow/44220639#44220639) rather than merely have *local-scope* reference.   ...which is obvious.

Once I have a persistent reference to the ancillary UIWindow, I can merely assign nil to it to remove it:

```
var hamburgerWindow:UIWindow?

 @IBAction func displayOverlayWindowAction() {
     guard hamburgerWindow != nil else {
         displayOverLay()
         return
     }
     hamburgerWindow = nil
 }
```